# Importing Xcode keybinds into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, xcode, intellij-idea, key-bindings, keymapping

As an iOS/Mac developer expanding his horizons into the world of Android, I have encountered a major problem. I use IntelliJ IDEA 15 for my Android development (it's amazing btw), but the problem happens with the keybinds. With Xcode, I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for building the project. There are countless others, and I was wondering if I could import these settings into my IntelliJ IDEA.

P.S. I know about the `Preferences -> Keymap` stuff, but going through each one and typing it in could probably take days. (I hope it won't come to that).

Comment: I'm running into the same problem the other way around.
The set I like is Eclipse, and I'm lucky in that Android Studio does have an "eclipse" options which gets most things right. Now I'm picking up Xcode and the key binds are driving me crazy. I did find a Eclipse keybindings for Xcode that may help me, but maybe for you, getting all your IDEs working the same way might just help. It won't be Xcode key bindings, but at least they will be consistent.

Comment: this is what I'm trying: https://github.com/andforce/EclipseStyleKeyBindings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA does not have any built-in support for importing keybindings from other IDEs. Generally speaking, since the set of actions to which keyboard shortcuts can be assigned differs greatly between different IDEs, migrating a set of keybindings from one IDE to another requires making decisions, and as such cannot really be automated.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. I have not tried it, but since Android Studio is built on IntelliJ, I don't see why not.

https://github.com/pitzcarraldo/IntelliJ-IDEA-Xcode-Keymap

Answer (score 1):

Improving on Brill's answer:

For Android Studio 3.1 to change keymap to xcode’s shortcuts. Need to import them manually. The raw keymap is here: https://github.com/pitzcarraldo/IntelliJ-IDEA-Xcode-Keymap

Create a directory called “keymaps” in: /Users/Jason/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.1

Restart Android studio. Open preferences->keymaps. You should be able to see it as a possible selection

Answer (score 1):

This plugin works. It is accessible by tapping plugins link within `Keymap` page in preferences (I was using IntelliJ 2022.2.2 community edition):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13093-xcode-keymap